# How to get 2 most recent values in postgreSQL in one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table of items in order:

```
orderitemid  orderid itemid quantity price      createdate
1                1     12     5     15.5         2016-12-04 11:35:02.06629
2                1     17     5     13.2         2016-12-04 11:32:02.06629
3                2     12     2     12.5         2016-12-05 11:35:02.06629
4                2     17     1     12.6         2016-12-05 11:35:02.06629
5                2     18     15    14.5         2016-12-04 11:35:02.06629
6                3     12     45     3           2015-12-04 11:35:02.06629
```

I have a query which gives the most recent order of each item so:

```
select distinct on (itemid) *
from orderitems
order by itemid,createdate
```

this gives:

```
orderitemid  orderid itemid quantity price      createdate
3                2     12     2     12.5         2016-12-05 11:35:02.06629
4                2     17     1     12.6         2016-12-05 11:35:02.06629
5                1     18     15    14.5         2016-12-04 11:35:02.06629
```

Now what I want is to get in the same row per item information about the previous order of the item. Basically to compare the most recent order of item with the 2nd most recent order of item

This is what I want:

```
orderitemid   itemid quantity price    2ndquantity 2ndprice 2ndorderitemid  
3               12     2     12.5         5         15.5         1
4               17     1     12.6         1         13.2         2 
5               18     15    14.5
```

How can I modify my query to do that?

Comment: Where is `partid` column in your example?

Comment: @OtoShavadze itemid. item and part are same. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The most recent order for itemid 12 is orderid 3, not 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with ranked as (
  select orderitemid, orderid, itemid, quantity, price, createdate, 
         row_number() over (partition by itemid order by createdate desc) as rn
  from orderitems
)
select r1.*, r2.quantity as "2ndquantity", r2.price as "2ndprice",
       r2.orderitemid as "2ndorderitemid"
from ranked r1 
  left join ranked r2 on r1.itemid = r2.itemid and r2.rn = 2
where r1.rn = 1;
```

The CTE calculates the 1st and 2nd items and the final select then brings them together with a join. Note that you need a left join as there might not be a 2nd row and in that case that item would not show up at all.

Online example: http://rextester.com/SDBZ21144

Comment: Shouldn't it be partition by itemid order by createdate DESC?

Comment: @avi Probably yes, I was just using the `order by` definition you used in your question (which states that it gets what you want, only for one row though)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm you want to compare all orderitem rows against the next most recent price?

```
WITH comparison_rank AS (
    SELECT orderitemid, itemid, price, quantity 
           rank() over (partition by itemid order by createddate)
      FROM orderitems
)
SELECT o.orderitemid, o.itemid, o.price, o.quantity, o.price, o.createddate,
       p.price as prevprice, p.quantity as prevqty
  FROM orderitems o JOIN comparison_rank c ON o.orderitemid = c.orderitemid
  LEFT JOIN comparison_rank p ON c.rank = p.rank + 1 AND c.itemid = p.itemid;
```

This will not perform so well over a large data set however.  To improve performance I think you need to improve your data model to improve performance.